# JS Promises - Why am I seeing the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning and DeprecationWarning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I am getting to grips with promises and how to set them up, however I can't see why node thinks my promise is unhandled when it comes to errors... Can somebody please explain?

**My simple code**

```js
    // Setting up the Promise
    function add(x, y) {
        return new Promise((response, reject) => {
            // Simple conditional (not perfect, but it just proves a point)
            if(x !== null && y !== null) {
                // I know I could have done 'response(x + y)', but I wanted 
                // to console.log the result also
                var calc = x + y
                response(calc)
                console.log('Calculation: ' + x + ' + ' + y + ' = ' + calc)
            } else {
                // My console does not throw this error?
                reject('One of the inputs was null')
            }
        })
    }
    
    // Function using the Promise
    function calc() {
        add(1, 3)
            .then(res => add(res, 3))
            .then(res => add(res, null))
            .then(res => console.log('Final result: '+res))
            .catch(err => {
                // This error is thrown in console
                throw new Error('Something went horribly wrong')
            })
    }
    
    // Run the code
    calc();
```

**Update**

I originally posted the 'reject' with a thrown error, of which I understand needs to be caught.

I also want to understand why the string in the 'reject' is not seen in my console?

Console output:

```
Calculation: 1 + 3 = 4
Calculation: 4 + 3 = 7
(node:61950) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Something went horribly wrong
(node:61950) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: If you throw a new error inside a `catch` clause, it will propagate down the promise chain. So you'll need a second `catch` to catch the error you throw in the first catch. And you probably just want to return the string inside the reject clause inside of throwing it, since what you return inside the reject will be used as the error inside catch.

Comment: Thanks @Shilly - I have edited my question. I understand what you mean about the thrown error needing to be caught, but how about if I don't throw anything, but just have `reject('some error message')`? I'm not seeing the error message in my console?

Comment: @Shilly - Ah, I understand that the `reject()` part is just like the `response()` part with it needing something to pass or to call at that point. Putting in `reject(console.log('Rejection message'))` DOES print to the console when it fails, however I am still receiving `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection`

Comment: You still throw an errror inside the catch that is unhandled. After your edit, `err` inside `catch` equals 'One of the inputs was null', since that's what you reject the promise with. So if you need to log both things to the console, just change the `catch` handler to `console.error( err ); console.error( 'Something went horribly wrong' )` so that both tne rejected text and the text inside catch get logged. Since that is your last catch handler, you want to end the error chain there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function using the Promise :

```
// Function using the Promise
function calc() {
    add(1, 3)
        .then(res => add(res, 3))
        .then(res => add(res, null))
        .then(res => console.log('Final result: '+res))
        .catch(err => {
            // This error is thrown in console
    --->    throw new Error('Something went horribly wrong')
        })
}
```

The line maked with `--->` throws an Error. That error isn't caught. Usually when you catch an error you want to do something with it. If you throw it back or throw another error, that throw should be caught.

What I'd do with this is the following :

```
// Function using the Promise
function calc() {
    return add(1, 3)
        .then(res => add(res, 3))
        .then(res => add(res, null))
        .then(res => console.log('Final result: '+res))
        .catch(err => {
            // This error is thrown in console
            throw new Error('Something went horribly wrong')
        })
}

calc().catch(err => {
    console.log(error.message); // For example
});
```

Comment: Is there any way of using the `reject()` part such that I don't have to put a `catch()` at the end of `calc()`? I changed the line to `reject(console.log('some error')` and that printed to the console but still with the deprecation error, but changing to `reject(new Error('some message'))` did nothing...

Comment: If you use `reject()`, you must `catch()` that rejection. But nothing stops you form simply logging the error without ever rejecting.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `reject` *and* throwing an error. You only need to do one of them.

You are not displaying the first error message.

It is also important to use `.catch` for any thrown error when you call `add`.

When you do this:
`throw new Error('Something went horribly wrong')`
you are still in a `promise` and if you don't catch it you are causing problems. In future versions of Node.js this will cause your application to exit with an error code. So you will need to make sure you always catch thrown errors within a promise.

**Using Reject**

```js
// Setting up the Promise
function add(x, y) {
  return new Promise((response, reject) => {
    // Simple conditional (not perfect, but it just proves a point)
    if(x !== null && y !== null) {
      // I know I could have done 'response(x + y)', but I wanted 
      // to console.log the result also
      var calc = x + y
      response(calc)
      console.log('Calculation: ' + x + ' + ' + y + ' = ' + calc)
    } else {
      // My console does not throw this error?
      reject(new Error('One of the inputs was null'))
    }
  })
}

// Function using the Promise
function calc() {
  return add(1, 3)
    .then(res => add(res, 3))
    .then(res => add(res, null))
    .then(res => console.log('Final result: '+res))
    .catch(err => {
      console.error("Internal Error:", err.message);
      // This error is thrown in console
      throw new Error('Something went horribly wrong')
    })
}

// Run the code
calc().catch((err) => {
  console.error("Outer error:", err.message);
});
```

**Using Throw:**

```js
// Setting up the Promise
function add(x, y) {
  return new Promise((response, reject) => {
    // Simple conditional (not perfect, but it just proves a point)
    if(x !== null && y !== null) {
      // I know I could have done 'response(x + y)', but I wanted 
      // to console.log the result also
      var calc = x + y
      response(calc)
      console.log('Calculation: ' + x + ' + ' + y + ' = ' + calc)
    } else {
      // My console does not throw this error?
      throw new Error('One of the inputs was null')
    }
  })
}

// Function using the Promise
function calc() {
  return add(1, 3)
    .then(res => add(res, 3))
    .then(res => add(res, null))
    .then(res => console.log('Final result: '+res))
    .catch(err => {
      console.error("Internal Error:", err.message);
      // This error is thrown in console
      throw new Error('Something went horribly wrong')
    })
}

// Run the code
calc().catch((err) => {
  console.error("Outer error:", err.message);
});
```

I added a `return` of the promise returned by `add` so you can `catch` the final error.

The other way to do it is to not throw the final error and handle it differently.